# A faster way to compute an array in thrust-cuda

Tags: graph, cuda, thrust

I have four arrays:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> vertices;
thrust::device_vector<int> adjacency:
thrust::device_vector<int> degree_summation;
thrust::device_vector<int> degree;
```

The indexes of vertices array represent the vertices of a graph while its content points to the first neighbour of each vertex in the adjacency array. The array degree stores the degree of each vertex in vertices.

I want the degree_summation array keeps the degree of each vertex plus the summation of the degree of each vertex neighbourhood.

```
Ex: Given the graph:
 0
/ \
1--2

vertices = {0,2,4}
adjacency = {1,2,0,2,0,1}
degree = {2,2,2}
```

What i want:

```
degree_summation = {6,6,6}
```

Currently, i am using a for loop to compute this value, but i think perhaps there is a faster way to compute these values using the primitives given by thrust. The kernel i use to compute the degree_sumation array:

```
__global__ void computeDegreeSummation(int* vertices,int* adjacency,unsigned int* degree_summation, unsigned int * degree,unsigned int num_vertices, unsigned int num_edges){
unsigned long int tid = (gridDim.y*blockIdx.y+blockIdx.x)*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
if(tid < num_vertices){
    int pos_first_neighbor = vertices[tid];
    int pos_last_neighbor;
    if(tid != num_vertices - 1){
        int it = tid;
        pos_last_neighbor = vertices[it+1];
        while(pos_last_neighbor == 0){
            it++;
            pos_last_neighbor = vertices[it+1];
        }
        pos_last_neighbor--;
    }//if
    else{
        pos_last_neighbor = num_edges - 1;
    }//else
    for(int nid = pos_first_neighbor; nid <= pos_last_neighbor; nid++){
        if(adjacency[nid]!=tid){
            degree_summation[tid]+=degrees[adjacency[nid]];
        }//if
    }//for
}//if
}//kernel
```

There is a if inside the for since i had initialized the degree_summation with the degree of each vertex before compute the kernel.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you have the `while` loop in your kernel.  Apparently your `vertices` array may have spurious zeroes in it? If you had a large data set to try it might be interesting to compare your kernel with thrust.  However your kernel doesn't look bad, and I could imagine it being faster than thrust in perhaps many scenarios.  The relative performance will be data-dependent.  Your kernel method will do less well when the neighborhoods are "long", and especially if there is a mix of long and short neighborhoods.   For short neighborhoods it is probably faster than my thrust code.

Comment: There is a mix of long and short neighbourhoods. Thus i guess it has decreased performance. I will create another array that stores the end of adjacency, i am thinking if it's gonna help me out somehow.

Comment: If there is any possibility to sort your vertices by neighborhood size, your kernel will probably perform better then.

Comment: I can try use the stable_sort_by_key(degree.begin(),degree.end(),vertices.begin())

Comment: You will need to move the corresponding neighborhoods in `adjacency` as well.  The `vertices` still need to be in ascending order, so I think this would effectively involve a "re-numbering/re-ordering" of your vertices.  I haven't thought through it fully.  I tried to think about creating a test data set so I could try comparing a kernel like yours to the thrust code, but it seemed difficult to create a synthetic data set.  If you could propose an algorithm to do so I would play around with it some more.

Comment: I am generating Barábasi-Albert Networks (some kind of synthetic scale-free graphs)  with NetworkX - a python library. If you have python and NetworkX installed, you can use: https://mega.co.nz/#!kINRSLYL!Yh94-1PQ9ZZNFm50nUNQfN5Zl3FqgMfMj4D1lNGLPAE or you can download a file of edges https://mega.co.nz/#!9ZVXyI7B!WZob6J7AXCH-2Ped2LOz21vkQFCvClYuSRb1nqKMLd0 or download http://snap.stanford.edu/data/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be faster - since I don't know how fast your reference implementation runs.  But this is one possible approach:

1. create a vector which defines the neighborhoods in `adjacency` for each vertex.

   ```
   vertices =     {0,  2,  4}
   adjacency =    {1,2,0,2,0,1}
   neighborhood = {1,0,1,0,1,0}  (after scatter)
   neighborhood = {1,1,2,2,3,3}  (after inclusive scan)
   ```

   To accomplish this, we will [thrust::scatter](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__scattering.html#ga8555284488141136aade6291d398126c) a set of 1's ([thrust::constant_iterator](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)) into a `neighborhood` array according to the indices provided by `vertices`, then do a [thrust::inclusive_scan](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums.html#gad57155adfbf01ba6660839aafe16ad71) on `neighborhood`.
2. We can then use [thrust::reduce_by_key](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad) using the `neighborhood` array as the keys, and using a [thrust::permutation_iterator](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) to select the value out of `degree` corresponding to each vertex listed in each `neighborhood` of `adjacency`.
3. We then just need to add `degree` to the intermediate `degree_summation` result produced in step 2.  We can use [thrust::transform](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#ga68a3ba7d332887f1332ca3bc04453792) for this.

Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t612.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

  // input data setup

  int h_vertices[] = {0,2,4};
  int h_adjacency[] = {1,2,0,2,0,1};
  int h_degree[] = {2,2,2};
  int vertices_size = sizeof(h_vertices)/sizeof(int);
  int adjacency_size = sizeof(h_adjacency)/sizeof(int);
  int degree_size = sizeof(h_degree)/sizeof(int);
  thrust::device_vector<int> vertices(h_vertices, h_vertices+vertices_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> adjacency(h_adjacency, h_adjacency+adjacency_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> degree(h_degree, h_degree+degree_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> degree_summation(degree_size);

  // create neighborhood array

  thrust::device_vector<int> neighborhood(adjacency_size);
  thrust::constant_iterator<int> first(1);
  thrust::scatter(first, first+adjacency_size, vertices.begin(), neighborhood.begin());
  thrust::inclusive_scan(neighborhood.begin(), neighborhood.end(), neighborhood.begin());

  // sum degree over the neighborhoods

  thrust::reduce_by_key(neighborhood.begin(), neighborhood.end(), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(degree.begin(), adjacency.begin()), thrust::make_discard_iterator(), degree_summation.begin());

  // add the vertex degrees

  thrust::transform(degree.begin(), degree.end(), degree_summation.begin(), degree_summation.begin(), thrust::plus<int>());

  // display results

  thrust::copy(degree_summation.begin(), degree_summation.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t612 t612.cu
$ ./t612
6,6,6,
$
```

(deleting the rest of my previous error. the alternative approach I had suggested was not valid.)